# Primitive roots and 'equivalent exponents'.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

If M is a primitive root mod p and M = $\ N^T$ mod p , then the order of N mod p is also (p-1) is this true?

Comment: One could say if M = N^T  mod p  then N is the T th root of M mod p ; so in general the integer root of a primitive root mod p ( if it exists) is also a primitive root .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. For suppose that $N$ has order $d\lt p-1$. Then $M^d=(N^T)^d=(N^d)^T\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. So $M$ has order $\le d$, contradicting the fact that $M$ is a primitive root of $p$.

**Remark:** More informally, since $M$ is a power of $N$, and the powers of $M$ range (modulo $p$) over the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,p-1\}$, so do the powers of $N$. "Everything" is a power of $N$, so $N$ is a primitive root of $p$.

Comment: If one writes the N th root of M mod p  is X meaning X to the exponent N is congruent to M mod p ; then the n the root of a primitive root mod p is also a primitive root.

Comment: That is a very nice intuitive description of the "why" of the matter.  It is more compact and clearer than my remark about "everything is a power of $N$."